# Removing a word from A text file

Tags: java, file, text

I have a method to remove a word from a text file in list format of words but it keep deleting all the data in the file instead of the specific word

```
 public static void Option2Method() throws IOException 
 {
   File inputFile = new File("wordlist.txt");
   File tempFile = new File("TempWordlist.txt");

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

   String lineToRemove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word to remove");
   String currentLine;

   while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
 {
   String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
   if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
   writer.write(currentLine);
 }
   boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code must call `close()` on the writer.

Make sure the data gets from the buffer to the actual file:

```
 while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
 {
   String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
   if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
   writer.write(currentLine);
 }

 writer.close();
 reader.close();
```

Consider using try/catch/finally blocks to make sure the streams are closed even when an `IOException` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = "Sample Line";
String[] words = str.split(" "); 
for(i=0 to i>arr.length)
{
if(str.indexOf(arr[i])!=-1) //checks if the word is present...
str.replace(arr[i],""); //replace the stop word with a blank
space..
}
```

Or this way:

```
String yourwordline = "dgfhgdfdsgfl Sample dfhdkfl"; 
yourwordline.replaceAll("Sample","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void removeLineMethod(String lineToRemove) throws IOException {
   File inputFile = new File("wordlist.txt");
   File tempFile = new File("TempWordlist.txt");

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
   String currentLine;

   while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
 {
   String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
   if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
   writer.write(currentLine + "\n");
 }
   reader.close();
   writer.close();
   inputFile.delete();
   tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
 }
```

if you do not delete the input file, your rename will fail, so close the streams, delete the input file, then rename the temp file.

Answer (score 0):

```
File inputFile = new File("wordlist.txt");
       File tempFile = new File("TempWordlist.txt");

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

   String lineToRemove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word to remove");
   String currentLine;

 while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
 {
   String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
   if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
   writer.write(currentLine);
   writer.newLine();
 }
   reader.close();
   writer.close();
   inputFile.delete();
   tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
    }
```